# Is there a way in Testdroid to email test reports?

Tags: testdroid

Is there a way in Testdroid to email test-reports automatically?
Ideally I would like to set up a configuration where after every test run, we can send everyone on a team the test results.

Answer (score 1):

1. Test finished hook:

Test finished hook: If you set hook URL, POST call will be sent to that URL when test run is finished.

But you will need to implement a web service etc for the mailing function.

2. Testdroid Cloud integration API

http://help.testdroid.com/customer/portal/topics/810087-testdroid-cloud-integration-api/articles